# digamma function inverse and special value

Tags: irrational-numbers, inverse-function, digamma-function

What is the inverse of the digamma function? Specifically, how can I solve for $x$ in:$$ ψ(x)=1$$$[x ≈ 3.20317146837693106929448152]$ without the digamma?

Comment: What does the displayed line mean? Just that $\psi(x) = 1$? And also then impose that $1<x$ ? Seems an unclear way to write what you mean...

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=digamma(x)%3D1

Comment: http://bariskurt.com/calculating-the-inverse-of-digamma-function/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Addressing the more general problem of equation
$$\psi (x)=k\tag 1$$ there is an interesting very recent paper (see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.06547.pdf)) which proves the following inequalities for the inverse of the digamma function
$$ \frac{1}{\log \left(1+e^{-x}\right)} \lt \psi^{-1} (x) \lt e^{x+\frac{1}{2}}$$ and the left bound seems to be a very good approximation of the considered function.

So, for a high accuracy, to find the zero of equation $(1)$, the starting value
$$x_0=\frac{1}{\log \left(1+e^{-k}\right)}$$ should be quite good.

Trying with the case $k=1$ given in the post, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 3.1922192845297391106277924019427161296056687330974 \\
 1 & 3.2031497228160267807035282180503621244715140401157 \\
 2 & 3.2031714682913142526893626274911788166676509691070 \\
 3 & 3.2031714683769310692931543294021138774273629843645 \\
 4 & 3.2031714683769310692944815249115036749619303929984 \\
 5 & 3.2031714683769310692944815249115036749619307119220
\end{array}
\right).$$